# How do I remove some specific array keys, if they have less than two values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multiple array with two different indexes  ( [IP] and [all_dates] )

the output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 72.xx.xxx.xxx
            [all_dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => [12/Oct/2015:00:30:15
                    [1] => [12/Oct/2015:00:30:24
                    [2] => [12/Oct/2015:00:30:49
                    [3] => [12/Oct/2015:00:30:57
                    [4] => [12/Oct/2015:00:30:57

 [2] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
            [all_dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => [12/Oct/2015:00:33:06
                    [1] => [12/Oct/2015:00:33:06
                    [2] => 
                )

        )

 [3] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 216.xxx.xxx.xxx
            [all_dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => [12/Oct/2015:00:41:09
                    [1] => 
                )
```

now I want to delete every array-keys where [all_dates] have less than 2 values

( like the [3] array )!

first of all I need to remove all the empty keys like ( `[2] => (empty` ). After this I can look after all the array-keys that have less than 2 values.

thanks for any help!

the output should look like this at the end:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 72.xx.xxx.xxx
            [all_dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => [12/Oct/2015:00:30:15
                    [1] => [12/Oct/2015:00:30:24
                    [2] => [12/Oct/2015:00:30:49
                    [3] => [12/Oct/2015:00:30:57
                    [4] => [12/Oct/2015:00:30:57

 [2] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
            [all_dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => [12/Oct/2015:00:33:06
                    [1] => [12/Oct/2015:00:33:06
                )

        )
```

This is how do I get my multiple array. I really cant explain why PHP always say my multiple array ( $ip_with_dates ) isnt defined.

```
$diff_ips = array_unique($ip_array);
foreach ($diff_ips as $ip) {
    $get_dates = shell_exec("grep $ip $path" . $inputs['domain'] . ".log | awk '{print $4}'");
    $array_date = explode("\n", $get_dates);
    $ip_with_dates[] = [
        'ip' => $ip,
        'all_dates' => $array_date
    ];
}
```

my try for a solution:

```
foreach ($ip_with_dates['all_dates'] as $dates) {
    array_filter($dates['all_dates']);
    if(count($dates['all_dates']) < 2){
        unset($dates);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apply condition like if COUNT of array [all_dates] < 2 then [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_filter()` for this process quite simply like this

```
<?php
$in = array(
    0 => array('ip' => '72.xx.xxx.xxx',
               'all_dates' => array(
                    '0' => '12/Oct/2015:00:30:15',
                    '1' => '12/Oct/2015:00:30:24',
                    '2' => '12/Oct/2015:00:30:49',
                    '3' => '12/Oct/2015:00:30:57',
                    '4' => '12/Oct/2015:00:30:57'
               )
      ),
   1 => array('ip' => '192.xxx.xxx.xxx',
              'all_dates' => array(
                    '0' => '12/Oct/2015:00:33:06',
                    '1' => '12/Oct/2015:00:33:06',
                    '2' => ''
              )
       ),
   2 => array( 'ip' => '216.xxx.xxx.xxx',
               'all_dates' => array(
                    '0' => '12/Oct/2015:00:41:09',
                    '1' => ''
             )
       )
);

$array = array_filter($in, function($element) {
                                return count($element['all_dates']) > 2 ? $element : '';
                           });

print_r($array);
```

Which will generate this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 72.xx.xxx.xxx
            [all_dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12/Oct/2015:00:30:15
                    [1] => 12/Oct/2015:00:30:24
                    [2] => 12/Oct/2015:00:30:49
                    [3] => 12/Oct/2015:00:30:57
                    [4] => 12/Oct/2015:00:30:57
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
            [all_dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12/Oct/2015:00:33:06
                    [1] => 12/Oct/2015:00:33:06
                    [2] =>
                )

        )

)
```

**RE: Your updated question**

instead of trying to fiddle with the array after its been created, why not do the test as part of the original array building process like this

```
$diff_ips = array_unique($ip_array);
foreach ($diff_ips as $ip) {
    $get_dates = shell_exec("grep $ip $path" . $inputs['domain'] . ".log | awk '{print $4}'");
    $array_date = explode("\n", $get_dates);

    if ( count($array_dates) > 2 ) {
        $ip_with_dates[] = [
                           'ip' => $ip,
                           'all_dates' => $array_date
                           ];
    }
}
```

Comment: did it was a mistake that the seccond sub-array has a [2] => (empty) value?

Comment: I updated my question. PHP say that my multiple array isnt defined, but I cant see why. At the bottom of my quesion you can see my array

Comment: So do a `print_r()` on the array and paste the result into the question

Comment: I did.. this above is the output. But I solved the problem with the not defined  array. I updated my quesion how my code looks right now. PHP have some problems with the all_dates index

Comment: See additional suggestion after you pasted the actual code to build this array

Comment: this have removed all the array with less than 2 array-keys! thats great :) I tried an array_filter on $ip_with_dates['all_dates'] but php still gives me an undefined index all_dates :o

Comment: As you dont put anything into the array with less than 2 elements, you dont need to run the `array_filter()` anymore

Comment: Can I ask whoever gave this a DV to explain why. Thanks

Comment: I need all the dates from every IP ( aslong the IP have more than one date time ). I need this because I have to know how long they have been on their website. ( like about 30 sec, or between 5 min and 30 min.....). Thats why I need at least two different date times for every IP. I know how to get the first datetime and the last datetime. Thats how I can see how long they have been on their website. It will be a problem if the last key of the all_date array is empty. Now I need to remove the last empty array key. I always did it with array_pop but this time it havent worked

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

1. use the [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to clean the `all_dates` sub-arrays of empty values.
2. Check if the total count of sub-array elements is `< 2`, and if so then unset the respective array.

lets say the parent array is `$parent`

```
foreach($parent as &$child){ // passing the elements by reference so un-setting them will affect the actual parent array. 
  if(isset($child['all_dates'])){ // maybe inconsistent data, so check if the "key" all dates is set 
    array_filter($child['all_dates']); // remove all empty elements
    if(count($child['all_dates']) < 2){
      unset $child;
    }
  } else { // if the key "all_dates" not set then discard the child. 
    unset $child;
  }
}
```

**Update based on edit:-**

You need to first define the array like

```
$ip_with_dates = array(); // oldschool array declaration
```

or

```
$ip_with_dates = []; // shorthand array declaration as of PHP 5.4
```

then proceed with the `foreach`.
as shown below..

```
        $ip_with_dates = array();
        $diff_ips = array_unique($ip_array);
        foreach ($diff_ips as $ip) {
            $get_dates = shell_exec("grep $ip $path" . $inputs['domain'] . ".log | awk '{print $4}'");
            $array_date = explode("\n", $get_dates);
            $ip_with_dates[] = [
                'ip' => $ip,
                'all_dates' => $array_date
            ];
         }
```

Comment: I did something like that a few minutes ago.. the problem is this wont work if I dont remove all the empty keys in the sub-arrays first.. there are some empty keys that shouldnt be there.. I always remove them with array_pop but this time this havent work because every time PHP gets me another reason..

Comment: oh wait.. i havent seen your seccond comment.. give me a sec :)

Comment: another problem is that php allways say my multiple array isnt defined.. and I cant explain why because I can print_r the array but if I want to work with the array, it allways give me a variable is not defined.. I will edit my question with my array

Comment: Updated my answer with the relevant solution.

Comment: ahh right.. I have forgotten this. Well I have tried it but PHP have some problems with my index. I updated my question again. 

There is any Problem with my 'all_dates' index. Do you see why?

Comment: _I can print_r the array_ then do `file_put_contents('array_dump.txt', print_r($theArray,true));`

Comment: as I said, I solved the problem with the not defined variable. Now the index is the problem : undefined index [all_dates].

Comment: updated my first code snippet to check if the incoming data has the respective array key set if not then discard the child array.